# How to solve $'''+ ''+  = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$'''+ ''+  = 0$$

What method can I use to further solve the equation?

Comment: Try using xy'''+y''=(?)'

Comment: More systematically, but not simpler, $x^3y'''+x^2y''=-x^3$ is of Euler-Cauchy type.

Comment: can you solve it setting y''=u ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write the first as
\begin{align}
(xy'')^{'} + \left(\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)' = 0
\end{align}
so it becomes a problem of integration, since of course the integrating process can be applied linearly. As such
\begin{align}
xy'' + \dfrac{x^2}{2} = C_1 &\implies y'' = \dfrac{C_1}{x} - \dfrac{x}{2}\\
&\implies \int y''(x) dx = \int \left(\dfrac{C_1}{x} - \dfrac{x}{2}\right) dx\\
&\implies y' = C_1 \ln x- \dfrac{x^2}{4}+C_2\\
&\implies \int y'(x) dx = \int \left( C_1 \ln x- \dfrac{x^2}{4}+C_2 \right)dx\\
&\implies y(x) = C_1 \int \ln x dx - \dfrac{1}{4} \int x^2 dx + C_2 \int 1 dx\\
&\implies y(x) = C_1 (x \ln x - x ) - \dfrac{x^3}{12} + C_2 x + C_3.
\end{align}

Comment: If the OP did not make any progress at all, it is better to give some hints instead of giving a complete solution.

Comment: @Gary I disagree. This is a place for complete questions and complete answers. Hints are only of commentary nature, and as such should be placed in the appropriate section.

An answer must be complete, elaborate and to the point. SE after all is a repository of questions and answers not a teaching tool.

Comment: This is true to some extent, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: @algevristis You lay down the law as if you run the place. Some of us who've been here a long time and have taught for 40+ years happen to disagree with you, so please watch your autocratic tone. Moreover, there has been a tendency of late to respond only to students who make some serious efforts on the problems they pose. This is NOT a place for doing students' homework for them.

Comment: @TedShifrin I never claimed it is. All I am saying is that an answer dejure requires of someone to start from point A, give detailed information about the process he is to follow, and arrive safely at point B. That's an answer in a mathematical perspective. Writing as an answer a comment like "Do this, then do that" etc. is not an answer since it does not provide quantitative ways of performing that (which arguably is the meat of maths). Math.SE is a repository of good answers, and where I can I point out the ones I disagree with.

Comment: @algevristis I would suggest that you read the [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/), which outlines site policy regarding question quality; and [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/), which describes how members of the community should respond to those who answer low-quality questions, and what further consequences might exist for those who persist in flouting community guidelines.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I apologize for all this. Will do.